# Select rows from two joined table that not in a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables:

**Table1:**
(EmployeeID int, EmployeeType int)

**Table2:**
(AllowanceID int, EmployeeType int)

**Table3:**
(EmployeeID int, AllowanceID int)

I need a query to select joined rows from the two tables(Table1, Table2) that result not in third one (Table3).

**I tried:**

```
Select t1.EmployeeID, t2.AllowanceID
From Table2 t2 Inner Join
     Table1 t1
     on t1.EmployeeType = t2.EmployeeType
where Not Exists (select 1
                  From Table3 t3 
                  where t3.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID and 
                        t3.AllowanceID = t2.AllowanceID
                 )
```

but no success.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
    [EmployeeType] [tinyint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [AllowanceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeType] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table3](
    [AllowanceID] [int] NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


Insert into Table1 (EmployeeID,EmployeeType)
Values
(352395,    10),
(352396,    16),
(352397,    15),
(352398,    10),
(3523991,   16),
(NULL,  16)

Insert into Table2 (AllowanceID, EmployeeType)
Values
(100,   50),
(30,    9),
(32,    10),
(37,    16),
(512,   28),
(6000,  10)

Insert into Table3 (AllowanceID,EmployeeID)
Values
(NULL,  352400),
(32,    NULL),
(37,    NULL),
(37,    352395),
(6000,  352395),
(30,    352396),
(32,    352396),
(37,    352396),
(512,   352396),
(6000,  352396),
(30,    352397),
(32,    352397),
(37,    352397),
(512,   352397),
(6000,  352397),
(30,    352398),
(32,    352398),
(37,    352398),
(512,   352398),
(6000,  352398),
(30,    352399),
(32,    352399),
(37,    352399),
(512,   352399),
(6000,  352399)
```

Comment: What does "no success mean"?  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: I second Gordon Linoff's request. As a note, I edited your post to add some line breaks into your code (didn't change anything in the code itself). As it was, it stretched very far and users had to scroll a lot to see everything. Just some feedback for future post formatting.

Comment: The code you posted seems fine to me, but without sample data (as DDL+DML), a clear problem description and desired results it's very hard to answer your question.

Comment: please provide sample data as text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that it expects `null` to equal `null`, [which is not how `null` works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx).

To correct that, simply change `t3.EmployeeID  = t1.EmployeeID` to `(t3.EmployeeID  = t1.EmployeeID or t1.EmployeeId is null)`.

The query becomes:

```
select 
    t1.EmployeeID
  , t2.AllowanceID
from Table2 t2
  inner join Table1 t1
    on t1.EmployeeType = t2.EmployeeType
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Table3 t3
  where (t3.EmployeeID  = t1.EmployeeID or t1.EmployeeId is null)
    and t3.AllowanceID = t2.AllowanceID
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OPRHN52820

```
+------------+-------------+
| EmployeeID | AllowanceID |
+------------+-------------+
|     352395 |          32 |
|    3523991 |          37 |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Perfect .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.EmployeeID, t2.AllowanceID
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.EmployeeType = t2.EmployeeType
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.AllowanceID = t2.AllowanceID AND t3.EmployeeID = 
t1.EmployeeID
WHERE t3.EmployeeID IS NULL
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a subquery with the desired tables and a Left join with the table where you want not to find the record:

```
Select A.EmployeeID, A.AllowanceID
FROM (SELECT t1.EmployeeID, t2.AllowanceID
From Table2 t2 Inner Join
     Table1 t1
     on t1.EmployeeType = t2.EmployeeType ) A
   LEFT JOIN t3 ON  t3.EmployeeID = A.EmployeeID and 
                    t3.AllowanceID = A.AllowanceID
WHERE t3.EmployeeID IS NULL and t3.AllowanceID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL SERVER then use following query

```
    SELECT t1.empoyeeId, t2.AllowanceId
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.EmployeeTypeId = t1.EmployeeTypeID 
EXCEPT 
SELECT employeeID , allowanceID
FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try EXCEPT, the sequence of use alters the results

```
SELECT t1.EmployeeID , t2.AllowanceID
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.EmployeeType = t2.EmployeeType
EXCEPT
SELECT t3.EmployeeID , t3.AllowanceID
FROM Table3 t3
;

SELECT t3.EmployeeID , t3.AllowanceID
FROM Table3 t3
EXCEPT
SELECT t1.EmployeeID , t2.AllowanceID
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.EmployeeType = t2.EmployeeType
```

> Returns any distinct values from the query to the left of the EXCEPT
>   operator that are not also returned from the right query. ([ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql))